# Openfire : No roster returned to user

Tags: mysql, xmpp, openfire, jappix

We added jappix mini chat feature in our application in conjunction with Openfire 3.7.1 and a Mysql database.

HTTP Binding is enabled in Openfire admin console.

The chat was working well on another server but it seems that we cannot get rosters anymore from client.
We always get the following empty response from Openfire when building contact list (buddies) :

Get request :

```
<body xml:lang='fr' rid='827616' sid='ad92bb0e' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' key='26620f678e64cc9f04ea31b69525db88c9655545' >
    <iq xmlns="jabber:client" type="get" id="1" xml:lang="fr">
        <query xmlns="jabber:iq:roster"/>
    </iq>
</body>
```

Response :

```
<body xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind'>
    <iq xmlns="jabber:client" type="result" id="1" to="atinel@domain/Chat (1452607565973)">
        <query xmlns="jabber:iq:roster"/>
    </iq>
</body>
```

This response can be seen in the browser network logs or in the audit logs from Openfire.
I only manage to get a roster when creating a new one between two users.

The rosters can be found in the database and in admin console where we see two of them for this precise user (atinel).
We also checked that the SQL queries on "ofRoster" table were properly formed for each user connection.

This is the kind of response expected :

```
<body xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind'>
    <iq xmlns="jabber:client" type="result" id="1" to="atinel@domain/Chat (1452608051572)">
        <query xmlns="jabber:iq:roster">
            <item jid="team@domain" name="IT Team" subscription="both"/>
            <item jid="userdemo@domain" name="Demo user" subscription="both"/>
        </query>
    </iq>
</body>
```

Have you any idea to solve this problem ?
Maybe I have missed a property when configuring Openfire ?

I already have cleared the roster (and all other) caches and nothing changed, no more result when upgrading to 3.9.3.

Thanks.

Comment: So was it working on OF 3.7.1 and not working on 3.9.3? It is unclear to me. Also please attach roster fetch request stanza aka stanza.

Comment: We have two platform with jappix chat installed. On the first one it works just fine with OF 3.7.1 but not on the second one (neither in 3.7.1 nor in 3.9.3). Sorry if I wasn't clear in the question. I will add the stanza directly in the question.